# How To Join These Tables in SQL normalising

Tags: sql, sqlite, normalization

I want to Join two tables in sql

e.g.:

```
        Table 1 
         ID 
         1
         2
         3

        Table 2
         ID        SEC
         1         Hospital
         1         Medical
         2         Clinic
         2         University
         3         College
```

I want result like

```
         ID       SEC
         1        Hospital, Medical
         2        CLinic, University
         3        College
```

Comment: Mureinink!  Thanks alot for editing, Not sure How to Add Like Table, Any hints?

Comment: What do you mean by "like table"?

Comment: While, I typing this post it is continuous text, Not Table View as you edited, Hows that magic...

Comment: Just leave a blank line between your regular text and your indented text - check out [how I did it](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26088376/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function, which would actually allow you to do this without even joining:

EDIT: Now that the comment explained the question is actually about [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) and not [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) as it was initially tagged, the syntax is slightly different:

```
SELECT   id, GROUP_CONCAT(SEC, ', ')
FROM     table2
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. It still getting error... near "SEPARATOR": syntax error:                 My Actual Code SELECT EXHIBITOR_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(SEC SEPARATOR ',')
FROM PRODUCTINFO
GROUP BY EXHIBITOR_ID

Comment: Sorry, it's the error FYI I'm Using SQL Lite Database Browser...Error

near "SEPARATOR": syntax error:

Comment: @PadmanabanGokula Ah! I was using [tag:mysql] syntax as per the tags of your question. [tag:sqlite]'s syntax is slightly different - I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

JOIN and then use GROUP_CONCAT with group by.

```
select T1.id , GROUP_CONCAT(SEC SEPERATOR ',')
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2
on T1.id = T2.id
GROUP BY T1.id
```